# Can't able to run program in codechef ide . get CodeChef NZEC error

Tags: java, exception

[Problem statement link](https://www.codechef.com/ENJA2020/problems/ECJAN20A)

So this code works fine in my system but got this error in codechef:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at Codechef.main(Main.java:14)
```

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Codechef
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        // your code goes here
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a,b,c;
    int T = scan.nextInt();
    int arr[] = new int[T];
    for(int i=0;i<T;i++){
        if(scan.hasNextInt()){
         a = scan.nextInt();
         b = scan.nextInt();
         c = scan.nextInt();
        if(a>=1 && b>=1 && c>=1 && a<180 && b<180 && c<180 && a+b+c == 180){
            arr[i]=1;
        }
       }

    }
    for(int i=0;i<T;i++){
        if(arr[i]==1)
        System.out.println("YES");
        else
        System.out.println("NO");
    }
    scan.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mainly caused because you have not provided custom input.
The InputBuffer is actually looking for Inputs but since you have not provided them explicitly this is causing the problem.

Once you try submitting it, it would be fine. The final verdict then depends upon your logic and implementation of the problem.

**Edit :** I would suggest using BufferedReader for Input Purposes, it is unbelievably much faster.

Added an image to help.
[image: Tried compiling use your solution to the Codechef IDE]